# C++ arrays - limit and size

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

How do you declare an array for a matrix that contains say 4 numbers (2x2)? I assume that `int m[4]` only allows numbers up to 4. Or does it mean any four numbers? I don't understand the difference.

Comment: `int` allows any integer within a large range. You have an array of four of those.

Comment: `int m[4];` declares an array of four integers. Each can have any value allowed by the `int` type. Doesn't your introductory book explain this in detail?

Comment: I advice to use `std::vector<std::vector<int>> m(2, std::vector<int>(2));` instead of an array.

Answer (score 3):

In a declaration

*type* **array_name**[ array_size];

*type* is the data type that this array stores. The particular value of array under index *i*, i.e. **array_name**[*i*] can be any of the values that *type* can represent.

In your example `int m[4];` declares an array of four **integers**. The particular value of any of these integers can be any of the values that **integer** can represent. To know these limits you can print them:

```
#include <limits>

int imin = std::numeric_limits<int>::min(); // minimum value
int imax = std::numeric_limits<int>::max(); // maximum value
```

Answer (score 2):

The use of STD should simplify your life in the construction of a matrix :

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> M(2, std::vector<int>(2));
```

But if you want to use arrays :

```
int x[2][2];
```

Answer (score 2):

`int m [4]` would declare an array with 4 uninitialized values of type integer. Remember that these values are **zero-indexed**, 
meaning that to call a value in the array you would call m[0-3]. You may assign any values you like to the array by the following command: `m[4] = {Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4}` If you prefer, you may also create a loop that will assign values to an array, which can be immensely useful at times.

Keep in mind that arrays are not commonly used in C++, `std::vector` is far more used, and for good reason.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: "int m [4] would declare an integer with 4 values" is wrong

Comment: NOPE: int m[4] does not declare AN integer. And an integer with four values is completely meaningless

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I believe it to be correct now. Thank you for your post.

Comment: "an integer array with 4 undefined values" - they're *uninitialised* values, not undefined, and given the question shows confusion over whether there are 4 supported values for one `int` or four distinct `int`s, your wording actually still leaves that ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`int m[4]` declares an array of 4 integers. The indexes of the integers will be 0, 1, 2, 3, while the values at those indexes can be any integers. so `m[2] = 2003;` sets the 3rd value in the array to 2003. As for the 2x2 aspect, you probably want to do something like `int m[2][2];` . I think about this as declaring an array of size 2, containing arrays at each spot, instead of ints or floats or whatever. The arrays contained at each spot (there are only two spots so only two arrays in this case) each hold two ints. So if the first value in your matrix is 32, you could set that by doing `m[0][0] = 32;` or more generally, `m[x][y] = value_of_(x,y);`
The quickest way to do what you described is probably this, if you know the values ahead of time:

```
int row0col0 = value at 0th row 0th column;
int row0col1 = value at 0th row 1st column;
int row1col0 = value at 1st row 0th column;
int row1col1 = value at 1st row 1st column;
int m[2][2] = {  {row0col0, row0col1},  {row1col0, row1col1} };
```

or equivalently:

```
int m[2][2] = {row0col0, row0col1, row1col0, row1col1};
```

This is referred to as row-major order: elements in a 2d array are sorted first by row, then by column.